# argparse: Remove whitespace after flags in --help and colorizing help output with colorama

Tags: python, formatting, argparse, flags, colorama

I've added some args to a script with argparse which function fine. Now I'm trying to format the `--help` output. I've added `metavar=''` to each one which has produced a much cleaner output, however there are spaces after the single flags making the text rag oddly.

#### Problems

Flag will display as `-m , --model` instead of `-m, --model`

Flags with `type=bool` with `const` and `nargs` display as `-x [], --xip []`, having the extra space and `[]` added.

Not finding much info on how to clean this up. Did find discussions on python.org that the extra space is a known problem and using `metavar=''` is not ideal.

example code:

```py
import argparse
import colorama
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init(autoreset=True)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=Fore.RED + 'Some descriptive Text and such' + Fore.WHITE, formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
add_arg = parser.add_argument
add_arg('-m',   '--model',  type=str, default='model_name',                     help="some help text", metavar='')
add_arg('-d',   '--derp',   type=str, default='burp',                           help="some more help text", metavar='')
add_arg('-x',   '--xip',    type=bool, default=False, const=True, nargs='?',    help="some other help text", metavar='')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

running `python script.py -h` produces:

```sh
usage: script.py [-h] [-m] [-d] [-x ]

Some descriptive Text and such # <-- this line displays as RED

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -m , --model         some help text (default: model_name)
  -d , --derp          some more help text (default: burp)
  -x [], --xip []      some other help text (default: False)
```

changing metavar to `metavar='\b'` produces this:

```sh
usage: script.py [-h] [-m] [-d] [-x ]] # <- extra bracket ]

Some descriptive Text and such

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -m, --model    some help text (default: model_name)   # indent broken
  -d, --derp     some more help text (default: burp)    # indent broken
  -x ], --xip ]  some other help text (default: False)  # indent broken
```

#### Coloring Output

I'd also like to know how to properly color the `--help` output with colorama. Coloring the description is easy enough, but trying to add coloring to the flags and such produced expected errors. Adding color to help worked if added before, like `help=Fore.YELLOW + 'some help text'`, but it colors everything after it, and can't add anymroe `Fore` after it without errors. Adding it anywhere else produces an error.

Is there a way to define how to color flags and help text, maybe outside of where they are being set?

Besides that, are there any packages for argparse formatting? I found some older ones that didn't work quite right but nothing new.

Comment: Try `metavar='\b'` to remove the space... not really a fan of spending time formatting `argparse` help.

Comment: @Bakuriu This removed the space, but it also broke the indentation on the help text (like a tab was deleted before the text). However, for the args with `const` and `nargs` it left the space and took out the left bracket, also broke the help text alignment. I'll edit my post to show what happens.

Comment: You could subclass the HelpFormatter, and modify the relevant method.  There's nothing you can do with existing parameters to make this display 'cleaner'.

Comment: Don't use `type=bool`.  The only string that yields `False` is `bool('')`, which your user cannot provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to figure it out after finding some old posts on SO.

The code from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280876/3927293) sets up an `add_argument_group`. You then add your args and hide the help text by setting `help=argparse.SUPPRESS`.

The actual text that is displayed in `--help` is the `title` and `description` of the group. This makes it very easy because you're just concatenating strings at that point and can add in your colorama styling easily with `+` where needed.

The code from the post:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Postfix Queue Administration Tool',
        prog='pqa',
        usage='%(prog)s [-h] [-v,--version]',
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        )
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action='store_true',
        help='Shows full overview of all queues')
g = parser.add_argument_group(title='information options',
        description='''-q, --queue <queue>     Show information for <queue>
-d, --domain <domain>   Show information about a specific <domain>''')
g.add_argument('-q', '--queue', action='store', metavar='', dest='queue',
        help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
g.add_argument('-d', '--domain', action='store', metavar='<domain>', dest='domain',
        help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.1')
parser.print_help()
```

My modified example code based on that post:

```py
import argparse
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init(autoreset=True)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + 'Some descriptive Text and such' + Fore.WHITE,
    prog='script.py',
    usage=Fore.WHITE + '%(prog)s [-m] [-d] [-x]',
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    )
g = parser.add_argument_group(title=Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + 'args',
        description=Fore.RED + '''
-m   --model        ''' + Fore.WHITE + Style.DIM + '''some help text       || default: model_name''' + Fore.RED + Style.NORMAL + '''
-d   --derp         ''' + Fore.WHITE + Style.DIM + '''some more help text  || default: burp''' + Fore.RED + Style.NORMAL + '''
-x   --xip          ''' + Fore.WHITE + Style.DIM + '''some other help text || default: False''' + Fore.RED + Style.NORMAL + '''\n\n''')
g.add_argument('-m',   '--model',   type=str, default='model_name',                      help=argparse.SUPPRESS, metavar='')
g.add_argument('-d',   '--derp',    type=str, default='burp',                            help=argparse.SUPPRESS, metavar='')
g.add_argument('-x',   '--xip',     type=str2bool, default=False, const=True, nargs='?', help=argparse.SUPPRESS, metavar='')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

The output:

```sh
usage: script.py [-m] [-d] [-x]

Some descriptive Text and such

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

args:
  
  -m   --model        some help text       || default: model_name
  -d   --derp         some more help text  || default: burp
  -x   --xip          some other help text || default: False
```

Attached image of what the output looks like in Terminal:
[image]

Lastly, as per @hpaulj 's advice, [I found this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357954/3927293) so I can change the type from `bool` and make sure it always resolves correctly.

```py
def str2bool(v):
    if isinstance(v, bool):
        return v
    if v.lower() in ('yes', 'true', 't', 'y', '1'):
        return True
    elif v.lower() in ('no', 'false', 'f', 'n', '0'):
        return False
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('Boolean value expected.')
```